# Skipping specific rspec tests in guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I'm trying to get the guard to skip some tests (those that require selenium to run).
I've added browser_required tag to them and running rspec with "--tag ~browser_required" filters them out.

However I can't get guard not to run them, I've set :cli => "--tag ~browser_required" in guardfile. This is my full guard file http://pastebin.com/pGuWAQm8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gist it does have two rspec blocks (one with cli and another without). Perhaps deleting the second one will at least get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Check my config: https://github.com/lucassus/locomotive/blob/master/Guardfile
You could pass cli arguments to rspec command and using `--filter` options you could reject some specs

`guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => "--drb --color --tag ~slow:true" {}`

In your example you can use `--tag ~js:true`

Answer (score 0):

The `cli` option is deprecated in Rspec 3. Use `cmd` instead.
For example:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: "bundle exec rspec --color --tag ~speed:slow", failed_mode: :focus do
  require "guard/rspec/dsl"
  dsl = Guard::RSpec::Dsl.new(self)

  # RSpec files
  rspec = dsl.rspec
  watch(rspec.spec_helper) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_support) { rspec.spec_dir }
  watch(rspec.spec_files)

  watch(%r{\Aapp/(.+)\.rb\z})   { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
end
```

Read more on Rspec tags [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/tag-option)